# Angular POST Request - How to access Response data

Tags: angular, rest, post, service

I am building a login/register page for my website. I have a django backend that returns an error if the email, username, or password field is left blank in my User model. I am able to successfully return errors when testing in Postman. My issue is capturing that data and passing it down to my html after my partially successful post request (partially successful in that I can register a new user to my backend).

Here's what I have:

**api.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {...

  private formatErrors(error: any) {
    return Observable.throw(error.json());
} 

...


post(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(`${environment.api_url}${path}`, JSON.stringify(body), { headers: this.setHeaders()})
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.formatErrors),
    map((res: Response) => res.json())
  );
}
}
```

I think everything above is okay unless I am misunderstanding the pipe()/catchError() methods in my post function.

I inject this into another service called **user.service.ts**, where I have a an attemptAuth function that utilizes the above post method:

```
 ...

attemptAuth(type, credentials): Observable<User> {
  let route = (type === 'login') ? '/login': '';
  return this.apiService.post('/users' + route, {user: credentials})
  .pipe(
    map(data => {
      this.setAuth(data.user);
      return data;
    })
  );
 }
...
```

That user service is imported into my **AuthComponent** and utilized here:

```
...
submitForm() {
  this.isSubmitting = true;
  this.errors = new Errors();

  let credentials = this.authForm.value;
  this.userService.attemptAuth(this.authType, credentials)
    .subscribe(
      data => this.router.navigateByUrl('/'),
      err => {
        this.errors = err;
        this.isSubmitting = false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea why my frontend is not picking up the response data being fed by my backend when a post request is being made? I don't believe my error takes place in my html or the component that I use to actually like the errors. I figured I would start with the above. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to get the response to a console.log(), `this.userService.attemptAuth(this.authType, credentials)
    .subscribe( response => {console.log(response);});`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your code is actual at the time, cause I don't think `Observable.throw()` exists anymore. It would be the `throwError` `operator` found in `rxjs`.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/throwError.ts

If you change the `Observable.throw()` to `throwError()` and `import` the `throwError` `operator` from `rxjs` like `import { throwError } from 'rxjs'`, that should at least make the Observable stream function (and break) like you expect it to.

Additionally, in your `catchError`, you will have `2 arguments`; 1 containing the error and another containing the `caught Observable` that is now broken. You don't have to throw another `error` yourself if you just want the `Observable` to break. `return caught` could achieve the same result within the `catchError()`, or you don't even have to use it if you have no error handling in itself.

I would still recommend you keep it, as it is good practice and quite explicit to communicate what you're trying to do. But there's no real error handling as of now.

Comment: Okay in my formatErrors function, I am now using `return throwError(error.json())`. Now in my catchError(), how would I go about supplying the "error" data that my backend supplies? Would it be similar to how I am doing it in the map() operator below?

Comment: Well firstly, you don't have to do `.json()` anymore on versions above Angular 2; the HttpClient now does it for you! :-D. 

The `error` is what comes in in the `catchError()`; so you can put a `console.log()` there to see what comes in exactly. `catchError()` isn't triggered if there's no error.  So it's basically a `map()` for errors only. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a few days back and I was getting an error while handling response because I was sending a text.
so below code solved my issue.

If your response is JSON change response type.

```
let apiurl = `http://localhost/api`;
    const requestOptions: Object = {
      //If your response is text not json
      responseType: 'text'
    }    
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(apiurl, data,requestOptions).pipe(map((data,error) => {
      if(data){
        return data;
      }
      else{
        return error;
      }
    })
    );
```

your component will look like this:

```
this.userService.attemptAuth(this.authType, credentials).subscribe(
      (data) => {
         console.log(data);
      }
    );
```